# Apache Spark - Scala - how to FlatMap (k, {v1,v2,v3,...}) to ((k,v1),(k,v2),(k,v3),...)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, flatmap

I got this:

```
val vector: RDD[(String, Array[String])] = [("a", {v1,v2,..}),("b", {u1,u2,..})]
```

wanna convert to:

```
RDD[(String, String)] = [("a",v1), ("a",v2), ..., ("b",u1), ("b",u2), ...]
```

Any idea how to do that using `flatMap`.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
vector.flatMap { case (x, arr) => arr.map((x, _)) }
```

Will give you:

```
scala> val vector = sc.parallelize(Vector(("a", Array("b", "c")), ("b", Array("d", "f"))))
vector: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Array[String])] =
               ParallelCollectionRDD[3] at parallelize at <console>:27


scala> vector.flatMap { case (x, arr) => arr.map((x, _)) }.collect
res4: Array[(String, String)] = Array((a,b), (a,c), (b,d), (b,f))
```

Comment: What if the second array is a HashMap? I tried the same function. The results just returns the first element of the map.

Comment: @kambiz If you have a *another question* regarding how to work with a `HashMap` now, I suggest opening a new question.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do so if that is the routine.

Comment: [Here you go.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507249/apache-spark-scala-flashmap-k-hashmapstring-doublev1-v2-to-k-v)

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely need to use `flatMap` like you mentioned, but in addition, you need to use scala `map` as well.

For example:

```
val idToVectorValue: RDD[(String, String ] = vector.flatMap((id,values) => values.map(value => (id, value)))
```

Comment: error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1 (see previous comment)

Answer (score 0):

Using single parameter function:

```
vector.flatMap(data => data._2.map((data._1, _)))
```