# Apache Spark - Scala - HashMap (k, HashMap[String, Double](v1, v2,..)) to ((k,v1),(k,v2),…)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, text-processing, bigdata

I got:

```
val vector: RDD[(String, HashMap[String,Double])] = [("a", {("x",1.0),("y", 2.0),...}]
```

I want to get:

```
RDD[String,(String,Double)] = [("a",("x",1.0)), ("a", ("y", 2.0)), ...]
```

How can it be done with FlatMap? Better solutions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
vector.flatMapValues(_.toSeq)
```

Comment: Error: value flatMapValues is not a member of scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Double]

Comment: vector is just the name of the RDD that could be anything.

Comment: I tried this instead:    vector.flatMapValues(x => x). It worked perfectly. Thanks for the hint!